# How to add {copyright, license, etc} to restructuredText source?

Tags: license-notice, documentation

I've got a lotta docs written in reST (note *docs*, not docstrings in code) to which I'd like to add (depending on the work) one or more of

- copyright notice
- license notice
- license badge/icon

I'd like to know, are there established conventions for this? Particularly:

I'm guessing this will involve adding to the doc(s) one or more [reST directives](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html), and furthermore probably

1. a [`meta` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#meta) with one or more fields for the copyright notice, license name, license URI, etc
2. *(if badging)* an [`image` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) with a field containing the standard URI for the license

If those assumptions are correct, my question becomes: are there canonical fieldnames for each of these data? If not in reST/docutils, are there fieldnames in {canonical, accepted, wide} use in a related domain, like a reST extension (e.g., Sphinx) or a related markup (e.g., Markdown)?

Answer (score 3):

RST supports [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783814/how-to-comment-a-string-in-restructured-text) in various forms, which could be used to specify licenses inline. This would be similar to adding a license block to an individual source code file in a program.

However.

If you are asking about something like a directory/subdirectory or a whole source code repository (e.g. a Github repo) with documentation, I personally would look for a file called `LICENSE` or similar in that directory/repository. Failing that I would open the starting page of the documentation and try to figure out where the license is mentioned. Honestly I haven't even considered up to now to try to look for a license block in the documentation source.

Github for example supports extracting the license name out of a `LICENSE` file,  I don't know if it is also able to do that with source code comments especially in a markdown language.